# javascript RegExp doesn't filter numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I got a problem with a javascript regex.

It doesn't stop numbers and "!" character while it should. 
It works for the others special characters, and of course I have debuged it to see if it really does the test, etc... and it does. It return true even if there is numbers in my String.

This is the RegExp :

```
new RegExp("^[^\\- ][A-Za-z\u00C00-\u017F\\- ]+"); // \u00C00-\u017F = À-S(latin)
```

It is to validate a first name in a form.

The problem is weird because I have exactly the same regex on the server side in java, and it works perfectly.

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do here?

Comment: @pimvdb: makes no difference. There's no ending anchor so it will almost always validate.

Comment: Yes. It is to validate a first name in a form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have some typo:

```
\u00C00-\u017F
```

C00 hex would be LARGER THAN 17F hex. But \u catches four characters only, see comment below.

Comment: +1 Good catch. The first four digits are bound to the `\u` but the `0` is not. So the range is really `0-\u017f` which includes digits
.

Comment: It is not that. I have try without it and it is still the same problem.

Comment: wow! It was that indeed. Rhaa, it was so stupid ><
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You should escape (for the javascript string) the regex `\u`

```
new RegExp("^[^\\- ][A-Za-z\\u00C0-\\u017F\\- ]+");
```

Also, if you are trying to match agains accented letters the range is (regex) `[\u00C0-\u00FF]`

Comment: The problem doesn't come form the unicode range. I did it without them yesterday and the problem was already here.

Comment: So you already had an error and made the code more complicated without fixing it before? Can you please show the statement where you do the test?

Comment: It works no, with the unicode corrected. I gess there was another errors before which made the same problem.